# Template overload resolution cost

Tags: c++, templates

I was watching this particular https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPWQ7xKfIHQ&t=836s CppCon talk about optimizing compile time of templates. Here he gives the following example

```
    template <typename Type, std::enable_if_t = is_list<Type>>
    struct pm
    {
    static auto read(Type& t) {....}
    static auto write(Type const& t) {...}
    };
```

And says that this would have a linear template overload resolution time complexity due to `enable_if_t`. I don't quite understand how template overload resolution is happening in this scenario. AFAIK compiler would first substitute type `T` in all the defined templates. This would mean looking into 2 possibilities. One with list and one without lists. After that it has a specific template instantiation that it is looking for and that should be just O(1) lookup. Could you please correct me what am I missing in my thinking process ?

Comment: It is a little unclear how the real code is, as shown usage is `pm::read(t)` which is wrong. Maybe he talks about the different overloads `template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<cond_v<T>> read(T&)` (for `is_list`, `is_integral`, ...) for which usage forces to check each overload (and select only the one which is correct). But I don't see how tag dispatching reduce instantiations here.